How to create video from a stream webcam and canvas?
I am trying to generate a video on browser from different cut:
Slide: stream from canvas
Video: stream from webcam
I just want to allow user to download the video edit with
slide1 + video1 + slide2 + video2 + slide3 + video3.
Here is my code:
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const webcam = document.getElementById('webcam');
const videoPlayer = document.createElement('video');
videoPlayer.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(videoPlayer);
const videoWidth = 640;
const videoHeight = 480;
let keepAnimating = true;
const frameRate=30;
// Attempt to get webcam access
function setupWebcam() {
 const constraints = {
        video: {
             frameRate: frameRate,
            width: videoWidth,  
            height: videoHeight 
        }
    };
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(stream => {
      webcam.srcObject = stream;
      webcam.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        recordSegments();
        console.log('Webcam feed is now displayed');
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error("Error accessing webcam:", err);
      alert('Could not access the webcam. Please ensure permissions are granted and try again.');
    });
}


// Function to continuously draw on the canvas
function animateCanvas(content) {
  if (!keepAnimating) {
    console.log("keepAnimating", keepAnimating);
    return;
  }; // Stop the animation when keepAnimating is false

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear previous drawings
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)}, 0.5)`;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.font = '48px serif';
  ctx.fillText(content + ' ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), 50, 100);

  // Request the next frame
  requestAnimationFrame(() => animateCanvas(content));
}


// Initialize recording segments array
const recordedSegments = [];
// Modified startRecording to manage animation
function startRecording(stream, duration = 5000, content) {
  const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'video/webm' });
  const data = [];

  recorder.ondataavailable = e => data.push(e.data);


  // Start animating the canvas
  keepAnimating = true;
  animateCanvas(content);
  recorder.start();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // Automatically stop recording after 'duration' milliseconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      recorder.stop();
      // Stop the animation when recording stops
      keepAnimating = false;
    }, duration);

    recorder.onstop = () => {
      const blob = new Blob(data, { type: 'video/webm' });
      recordedSegments.push(blob);
       keepAnimating = true;
      resolve(blob);
    };
  });
}

// Sequence to record segments
async function recordSegments() {
  // Record canvas with dynamic content
  await startRecording(canvas.captureStream(frameRate), 2000, 'Canvas Draw 1').then(() => console.log('Canvas 1 recorded'));

      await startRecording(webcam.srcObject,3000).then(() => console.log('Webcam 1 recorded'));

          await startRecording(webcam.srcObject).then(() => console.log('Webcam 1 recorded'));
  mergeAndDownloadVideo();
}

function downLoadVideo(blob){
 const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  // Create an anchor element and trigger a download
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'merged-video.webm';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();

  // Clean up by revoking the Blob URL and removing the anchor element after the download
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
}
function mergeAndDownloadVideo() {
  console.log("recordedSegments length", recordedSegments.length);
  // Create a new Blob from all recorded video segments
  const superBlob = new Blob(recordedSegments, { type: 'video/webm' });
  
  downLoadVideo(superBlob)

  // Create a URL for the superBlob
 
}

// Start the process by setting up the webcam first
setupWebcam();

You can find it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Sulot/nmqf6wdj/25/
I am unable to have one "slide" + webcam video + "slide" + webcam video.
It merges only the first 2 segments, but not the other. I tried with ffmpeg browser side.

You need to narrow down this problem.  If all your individual video clips are recorded fine, then the problem has nothing to do with 95% of the code here, and is only related to your playback and switching, yeah?

Yes, you are supposedly 100% right. However I am unable to understand where the problem is. I remove the "play" part as I download it. And the download does not work. And no the video clip are not individualy right, only the first ones.

Ok, I see now that you're trying to merge the videos from completely different videos?  That isn't going to work.  You have different track data from the canvas and webcam and what not.  You can't just concatenate arbitrary chunks of video like this.  Additionally, what comes out of MediaRecorder are not standalone chunks.  They are just parts of a long video stream.  There are two ways to do what I think you want to do... either take your independent video streams and handle the splicing server-side, OR just draw everything to the canvas and record the canvas as one stream.

There is a third way, which is to ditch the MediaRecorder and use the Web Codecs API, but that's more complicated than you need, and still doesn't solve your initial problem of switching streams.  You'd still need to draw everything on that canvas.

So I was able to do what I wanted using: MultiStreamsMixer
https://github.com/muaz-khan/MultiStreamsMixer
